# Liferay 6.0.6 JSF 2 portlet deployment issue

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, liferay

I have strange issue with Liferay 6.0.6 portlet deployment to Jboss EAP 5.2 server
The code that was working for years suddenly stopped deploying. Portlet is using JSF 2.1.21

The Error from server log:

```
2021-03-10 13:38:10,918 INFO  [STDOUT] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)   Expanding: E:\Jboss\eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\deploy\example-portlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war into E:\Jboss\eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\jboss-as\server\default\javaiotmp\20210310133810918
2021-03-10 13:38:12,146 INFO  [STDOUT] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)   Copying 1 file to E:\Jboss\eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\jboss-as\server\default\javaiotmp\20210310133810918\WEB-INF
2021-03-10 13:38:12,305 INFO  [STDOUT] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)   Copying 1 file to E:\Jboss\eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\jboss-as\server\default\javaiotmp\20210310133810918\WEB-INF\classes
2021-03-10 13:38:12,324 INFO  [STDOUT] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)   Copying 1 file to E:\Jboss\eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\jboss-as\server\default\javaiotmp\20210310133810918\WEB-INF\classes
2021-03-10 13:38:12,734 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner) com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.
2021-03-10 13:38:12,734 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:338)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,734 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.SAXReaderUtil.read(SAXReaderUtil.java:115)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,734 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.PortletDeployer.setupJSF(PortletDeployer.java:473)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.PortletDeployer.getExtraContent(PortletDeployer.java:144)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.updateWebXml(BaseDeployer.java:1414)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployDirectory(BaseDeployer.java:493)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:828)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:765)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deploy(BaseDeployer.java:454)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployer.autoDeploy(PortletAutoDeployer.java:92)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener.deploy(PortletAutoDeployListener.java:78)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoDeployDir.java:180)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(AutoDeployDir.java:221)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeployScanner.java:49)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner) Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:335)
2021-03-10 13:38:12,735 ERROR [STDERR] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner)    ... 13 more
2021-03-10 13:38:12,736 INFO  [STDOUT] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner) 13:38:12,735 INFO  [PortletAutoDeployListener:81] Portlets for E:\Jboss\eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\deploy\example-portlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war copied successfully. Deployment will start in a few seconds.
```

Looking to liferay code it's failing trying to parse faces-config.xml file

faces-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.medpro.messageresources.MessageResources</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en_US</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <message-bundle>com.medpro.messageresources.MessageResources</message-bundle>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>com.liferay.faces.util.lifecycle.DebugPhaseListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

</faces-config>
```

I don't see any issues with
eap-5.2-Liferay-6.0.6\jboss-as\server\default\javaiotmp\20210310133810918\WEB-INF\faces-config.xml

I also tried to download http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd it's downloading valid xsd file.

Please advise what is possible reason for deployment failure ?

UPD:
please note that http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd is redirected to http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd

[image]

if I replace the url in faces-config.xml to http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd the deployment works fine.

Comment: 6.0.6 !? very old !  Have you changed the jvm? Have you changed some permissions?

Comment: The problem is probably on our proxy side if I change xsd to http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd it works fine.

Comment: It appeared that issue is also reproducible outside of our network without proxy. Similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731870/premature-end-of-file-on-beans-xml  Looks like redirect is causing an issue in my case too.

Comment: Not sure if something changed on oracle web site side that starts causing an issue. similar jboss  issue here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4240421